# How to build deb package to contain single assembly jar with sbt-assembly and sbt-native-packager?

Tags: sbt, apache-spark, sbt-native-packager, sbt-assembly

Is it possible to use the `sbt-assembly` and `sbt-native-packager` plugins to create a java application archetype installation that instead of having the project jar and its dependencies in `<app>/lib` contains just the assembly jar?

I've built a Spark application and I want to add the assembly to the context rather than adding each jar individually.

Edit: I need to build deb packages for deployment. I want the deb package to contain the assembly not the project & dependent jars.

The filesystem layout should be

```
<install_dir>
     bin
         appname
     conf
         application.conf
     lib
         appname-assembly.jar
```

sbt-native-packager adds a symlink to /usr/bin which is convenient but not necessary.

Comment: Can you add the expected deb package layout and how do the files relate to the project?

Comment: edited question to add the file layout

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with native package. A full example can be found [on github](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/tree/master/assembly-one-jar)
You have to change the **mappings** and the **scriptClasspath**

Your **build.sbt** should contain the following parts

```
// the assembly settings
assemblySettings

// we specify the name for our fat jar
jarName in assembly := "assembly-project.jar"

// using the java server for this application
packageArchetype.java_server

maintainer in Linux := "Nepomuk Seiler <nepomuk.seiler@mukis.de>"

packageSummary in Linux := "Custom application configuration"

packageDescription := "Custom application configuration"

// removes all jar mappings in universal and appends the fat jar
mappings in Universal := {
    // universalMappings: Seq[(File,String)]
    val universalMappings = (mappings in Universal).value 
    val fatJar = (assembly in Compile).value
    // removing means filtering
    val filtered = universalMappings filter { 
        case (file, name) =>  ! name.endsWith(".jar") 
    }
    // add the fat jar
    filtered :+ (fatJar -> ("lib/" + fatJar.getName))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) plugin could be of help (instead of relying on the other plugins - sbt-assembly and sbt-native-packager):

> sbt-onejar is a simple-build-tool plugin for building a single
>   executable JAR containing all your code and dependencies as nested
>   JARs.

Comment: I've updated the question to state that I need to produce a deb package as sbt-native-packager does.